# image onclick event not working

Tags: image, onclick, jquery

im tryin to make a onclick event for my image, but its not workin..the alert is not showing up..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.closeAttrIcon').click(function(){
        alert("ww");
    });
});
```

even if i try like this with ..bind.. no hope...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.closeAttrIcon').bind('click',function(){
        alert("ww");
    });
});
```

the html will be created during this event:

```
$('a#btnAddStdntAttr').click(function(){
    var newAttr = '<div class="attrParent"><br class="clear"><label></label><input type="text" id="stdntAttributeKey1" maxlength="250" style="width: 13%;" name="stdntAttributeKey1"/>';
    newAttr+= '<input type="text" id="stdntAttributeValue1" maxlength="250" style="width: 13%;" name="stdntAttributeValue1"/>';
    newAttr+= '<img src="<c:url value="/static/images/closeIcon.png"/>" onclick="removeStdntAttr();" class="closeAttrIcon" alt="Close" title="Close" /></div>';
    $(this).after(newAttr);
});
```

what am i doing wrong here..please help..

Comment: how can you put <br> in java script

Comment: post the html it is supposed to match

Comment: @Prabhavith.. oo.sorry..tat was just my silly mistake during posting this question to here..i have edited the question..

Comment: if i manually add onclick event to the image and create a function for it..it works.. but why this jquery click function not working...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not work because you are injecting it after the DOM is created for the first time, for that you need to use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (if using til jQuery 1.7) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if using (1.7+) binding method

change your call to:

```
$(function(){
   $('img.closeAttrIcon').live('click', function() {
        alert("ww");
    });
});
```

if you're using jQuery 1.7+ then you can also do this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.closeAttrIcon', function() {
    alert("ww");
});
```